# w1-gpio and DS18B12 always return t=85000

Tags: gpio, 1-wire

I am having a DS18B20 temperature sensor in a 3-wire setup (using a pullup resistor of 4.7 kOhm from data to 3.3v) on a Raspberry Pi model B+. It always return the value as shown below when using `cat w1_slave` to get the data:

```
50 05 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 1c : crc=1c YES
50 05 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 1c t=85000
```

It is not the problem of a particular DS18B20 as I have replaced it with another one and get the same result.

I also tried to unplug the three jumper wires from the Raspberry Pi header and connect into an Arduino without touching any circuit or connections on the breadboard, the same circuit works perfectly on my Arduino Pro Mini (3.3v). So it is not the problem in circuitry.

I also tried it on two different Raspberry Pi and get the same result.

The `/boot/config.txt` is enabled with the setting of `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` and gpiopin4 is used as default for input (in fact I tried different gpio pin configurations, but the results are the same).

Any one has the similar experience? Am I missing something?

**Update**

Here is the photo of my breadboard wiring:

[image]

As per @joan's comment, I also decided to solder the DS12B18 and the pull up resistor direct to the back of Raspberry Pi header connector to make sure verify that the problem is not due to pure join to connectivity (see the picture), but I get the same result.

[image]

Comment: *Am I missing something?* - yes, in the question you haven't shown where/how you are getting these readings - in arduino-land you not only need *1-wire* library to speak to a DS18B20, you also need the *DallasTemperature* library to communicate with that particular sensor

Comment: I am afraid it is a problem with the circuitry.  Make sure all the joints are good and post a clear photo of your Pi connections.

Comment: @Jaromanda, I don't have the problem when using it on Arduino.

Comment: @joan, the same circuitry plug into an Arduino works perfectly without any problem, therefore it is not the joints and connection on my breadboard.

Comment: Suit yourself.  85 is returned when there is a communications failure.    Communications failure is caused by poor circuitry.

Comment: The fact that it works in arduino suggests the fault is in **software** which I suggested you add to the question but if you don't want help then god speed

Comment: @Jaromanda, I know that Dallas Temperature library is required in the case of Arduino, but I'm not aware that Raspberry Pi need to load a separate Dallas Temperature library other than enabling the w1-gpio overlay, where and what commands to get the library for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @jaromanda Is it possible that you have the Parasitic power (PAR) version of the device. The parasitic version would work better when the the GPIO pullups are activated on the pi, which is what you saw.

Comment: Nope. Don't have that version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @Ghanima's suggestion, repost my updated as a separate answer.

I've solved the problem by myself by changing the `/boot/config.txt` settings from

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

to

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio, pullup=on
```

According to the /boot/overlays/README, the `pullup=on` would only needed if it is operated in 2-wire parasitic mode. My configuration is clearly not running in parasitic mode, but nevertheless, this seems to solved the problem, and I can get the temperature data consistently and correctly.

**Information abstracted from /boot/overlays/REAME**

```
Name:   w1-gpio
Info:   Configures the w1-gpio Onewire interface module.
        Use this overlay if you *don't* need a GPIO to drive an external pullup.
Load:   dtoverlay=w1-gpio,<param>=<val>
Params: gpiopin                 GPIO for I/O (default "4")
        pullup                  Non-zero, "on", or "y" to enable the parasitic
                                power (2-wire, power-on-data) feature
```

### Further update

When I posted my question a year ago, I also had a USB Software-Defined Radio (SDR) plug in the Raspberry Pi along with DS18B21 sensor, the SDR draws a lot of current, by disconnecting the SDR, I'm able to get the temperature reading correctly most of the time, and only occasionally getting a reading of 85000. This suggests that in order for DS18B20 to functional properly, make sure you have stable power supply able to provide 5V@2A.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with only one sensor. After a lot of trial and error I finally got it to work when I swapped my 3V3 pin from pin 17 to pin 1.
Don't know the reason behind this as both should have the same voltage readings, but whenever I get hold of a voltage meter I will check it out.